# VBA do until loop conditioning?

Tags: vba, excel

I have to use 'DO UNTIL' condition if certain conditions are met i will give an

example here.

For the cells(9,3) in an sheet, i have to check whether the cells(9,3).value is

Empty or its "0". If it is so, i have to ask input from the user and it should

be inbetween 1 to 100. i wrote code like this

```
DO until 1<AA<100
  if cells(9,3).value="" or cells(9,3).value="o" then 
     AA=InputBox("cells(9,3).value", "Enter only values  as  Numeric  ", "give the value Here")
  else
      AA= cells(9,3).value
  end if
loop
```

but its not doing after do until it skipping all the steps. please help.

Comment: your code doesn't make at all :)

Comment: @gsharp neither your comment :v

Comment: Use `Loop Until` instead so that the code will run at least once...

Comment: @MacroMan it's unnecessary, once he correct the loop condition it will be running perfectly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with the code is that everytime the condition **(1 < AA < 100)** will return true:

The code interpretation will be like this

```
C1 = (1 < AA)
C2 = C1 < 100

So, if:
AA > 1 Then C1 = 1 (True as VBA don't use strong types operators)
And if:
AA < 1 Then C1 = 0 (False as VBA don't use strong types operators)
Annnnd if:
AA is text, then C1 = 1 (Every non numeric character is bigger than an integer for VBA)
Then:
C1 = 1 or 0 or 1

The second condition will be:
C2 = C1 < 100
then 
if C1 = 0 or if C1 = 1 both are less than 100, it causes that C2 will aways be true.
```

All you need to do is to use three conditions, like:

```
Do Until IsNumeric(AA) And 1 < AA And AA < 100
```

Comment: Thank you Very much Diogo, for taking your time to explain and answering it properly, now i understand.